# Keen IO Php client connection issue

Tags: php, eclipse, google-chrome, keen-io

I'm trying to use keen.io in PHP application. The below code works fine from a eclipse ide but shows connection reset from chrome/firefox.

Any help is much appreciated.

1. I used phpunittest to assert that instances are working fine. The test went successful. The analysis event has been verified in a js client and it works fine.
2. Now i tried creating a debug profile from eclipse ide and i ran it both the create event and analysis event were successful
3. When i try from Chrome/firefox there is no response. Inspection in to the debugger shows Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in chrome

Environment
PHP version is 5.5.12
WampServer
Windows 8
Local Applicaion

**Edit:** I further debugged it through the xdebug add-on for chrome and eclipse  to find that the code broke in the following method

/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/AbstractCommand.php - Line Number 330 where it has the function "protected function validate()".

Once i commented this everything seems to go fine.

Here is the code

```
<?php
namespace KeenIO\Tests\Client;
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

include('/Firebase/TokenException.php');
include('/Firebase/TokenGenerator.php');

use Firebase\Token\TokenException;
use Firebase\Token\TokenGenerator;
use KeenIO\Client\KeenIOClient;
use Guzzle\Tests\GuzzleTestCase;

class KeenIOClientTest extends GuzzleTestCase
{

    public function testThisMightHaveADb()
    {
        $projectId = "544a8064072719342addb0d5";        
        $readKey = "b2ec296d6a26d7208af256ea28361bfa0bfd8d3ec2989a2650505596bd33251c96293c90a5dc5a0b476211c30f477436a5b6ef58aa59e4e5259ab8faed48f5c0f418d7754920642651ab97a53c213d38a649fb9278f114ddf64592eff78d53f269fffb334ebb093ba88fbdbc851e33fb";


        $client = KeenIOClient::factory([
                'projectId' => $projectId,
                'writeKey'  => $writeKey,
                'readKey'   => $readKey
        ]);

        echo "done";

        //Check that the Client is of the right type
        $this->assertInstanceOf('\Guzzle\Service\Client', $client);
        echo "1";
        $this->assertInstanceOf('\KeenIO\Client\KeenIOClient', $client);
        echo "2";
        //Check that the pass config options match the client's config
        $this->assertEquals($projectId, $client->getConfig('projectId'));
        echo "3";
        $this->assertEquals($writeKey, $client->getConfig('writeKey'));
        $this->assertEquals($readKey, $client->getConfig('readKey'));

        echo $client->getProjectId();


        $average = $client->average("temprBugs", ["target_property" => "PF", "timeframe" => "previous_5_days"]);

        print_r ($average);
    }
}

$testObject = new KeenIOClientTest();
$testObject ->testThisMightHaveADb(); 

?>
```

Comment: Are those your real production `$readKey` and `$writeKey` values?  If so, you might want to get new ones, since now they are publicly available.  Also you might update your post to include dummy values for those variables.

Comment: Thanks for the note @Castaglia They are just dummy ones.